# REGEX insert character every n-times starting at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m not very fluent in REGEX, but I have this sequence:
`/(.{3})/g`
As far as I know, this would match every 3 characters starting at the beggining of the string. 
How can I start from the end of string and insert a '.' (period character) between them?

Extra info: The user will input numbers and I would like it to insert a '.' after every 3 numbers. It´s a custom made Mask I´m building for a specific project.

Thanks

Comment: 1) show a few examples of expected input and respective output. 2) show what you've tried. 3) what does it mean to insert something between "an end" that you want to "start" from.

Comment: "I´m not very fluent in REGEX" >> [Regular Expression Pocket Reference](http://roydukkey.com/regular-expression-pocket-reference/)

Comment: Sorry for not providing a example before, but @Cranio already awnsered it.
Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like:

```
numberString.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
```

Just be sure that numberString is indeed a *string*, or convert it with `.toString()`.

**Explanation:**
This is very tricky; it will match every digit `(\d)` that comes before a group of three digits `\d{3}` or this group repeated more than once `(\d{3])+` (so every multiple of three) that is not followed by another digit `!\d`

It uses *positive lookahead* (`?=`) and *negative lookahead* (`?!`) in order to match or exclude parts of the strings without including them into the match results.

Then it replaces the first matching group (the digit) with itself (using the *backreference* `$1`) followed by a dot.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Updated my answer

Comment: Nice one +1: _https://regex101.com/r/aD9tM9/1_

Comment: Sorry for not providing a example before. But to make it work with my code I had to  change it a bit:
`  /(\d{3})(?=(\d{1})+(?!\d))/g, "$1." `
It worked just fine. Also thanks for the explanation e all other replies!